# OWASP security issue with jackson-databind-2.9.8 jar

Tags: security, java-8, java-11, owasp, jackson-databind

I have a maven web project(RESTful, Spring Rest/data) running in Java 8(tomcat 8.5.5) and using 'jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar'. When the *Dependency Check Tool*(Checks vulnerable jar version and generates report) is run against the libraries the project is using, it showed 'jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar' as *Vulnerable*(**Reference-** https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Advanced&results_type=overview&search_type=all&cpe_vendor=cpe%3A%2F%3Afasterxml&cpe_product=cpe%3A%2F%3Afasterxml%3Ajackson-databind&cpe_version=cpe%3A%2F%3Afasterxml%3Ajackson-databind%3A2.9.8)

**Problem:-** Changing to 'jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar' version fixes OWASP security issue(running *Dependency Check Tool*) but, when project is build and run it throws error since 2.10.0 uses jdk9+ complaint classes(**Reference-** https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.10)

What should be done to resolve the issue, can we make the project compile in Java 8 and run in JDK11(since JDK9 is out of support) or something else should be done? Please suggest.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

CVE-2019-12086 is fixed in `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar` .

See the report: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-12086

Maven repo for 2.9.9 : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9

Comment: Yes, I tried this version which also didn't pass through the Dependency-Check Tool, please refer to the URL reference above in my comment.

Comment: @Nikhil 2.9.9 does not fix all of those CVEs. Therefore you should use the latest 2.9.x version which is currently 2.9.10.2. It contains a lot more fixed CVEs.

Comment: @NikhilSinghBhadoriya , what Robert just said is what i would always do rather than jumping to a major version.